# How to refresh only a single level of project hierarchy in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Is there any way or hack to limit a refresh action (F5 or right-click->refresh) to refresh the selected directory non-recursively, i.e. to stop without refreshing the child directories (recursively)?

The problematic directory is an sshfs-mount which is very large and extremely slow to refresh, so extremely, that I have never managed to wait for the refresh to complete. Even cancelling it doesn't always work properly - I have to kill Eclipse, though after restarting, the directory tree had been refreshed to a certain level, and I can rinse and repeat until I have refreshed the part of the tree that I need. It's painful, to say the least.

Comment: Eclipse MUST be used locally. It's a mistake to attempt to use it remotely or with networked resources. For that kind of usage, vi(m) is the best. ;-)

Comment: I think it is used locally but a folder used in his project is remote.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the automatic refresh feature. I don't know if it blocks the UI but if if doesn't then you don't care if this folder takes 5 years to be refreshed :)

> Window > Preferences > General > Workspace

Check "Refresh on access" if it is available, or "Refresh using native hooks or polling" otherwise.

Comment: I very much care whether it takes 5 years to refresh or not, because the directory *I need* may be refreshed in the last year -- not acceptable. I have the `Refresh on access` option enabled, but clicking on a directory that was not refreshed does nothing (and shows no contents underneath). Refreshing it manually enters the amazingly long recursive refresh loop again (though for a slightly smaller hierarchy).